# Single CollectionView for Multi Tab SegmentControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to display two collection view using segment controller, on change of segment second collection view will display.
my code is :

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"morningcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UICollectionViewCell *cell1 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"eveningcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (_segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {


    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.height,cell.frame.size.width)];
    lbl.text = [numbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    return cell;
}
else{
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell1.frame.size.height,cell1.frame.size.width)];
    lbl.text = [numbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell1 addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    return cell1;
}}
```

Comment: Your question is not clearly stated.

Comment: I add everything clearly. If you dont understand anything you can comment. Don't do direct judgements. @hardikparmar

Comment: What it's your question? Your question is not clear (Really you don't make any question)

Comment: And what's wrong with your code?

Comment: Form question you title you are saying that you are working with 2 collection view and from code, you have used 2 collection view cells.....s its bit confusing what you are trying to say...

Comment: Two different collectionview has two different collectionview items. Both collectionviews are on same page.

Comment: I got this error @Larme : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier morningcell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: At least, we get an error message. That error is pretty explicit, and have numerous questions and answers on SO. But you need to show a screen of your app or explain it, because you have two UICollectionView or two kind UICollectionViewCells? Do you really have to use two UICollectionView? `[cell addSubview:lbl];` let's say that the chance of breaking the reuse is high (especially since you seem to be new).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Do not create two collectionView for the task that you want because you can achieve it using a single collectionView.


@interface YourVC(), UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
NSArray *arrayOfModelsForFirstCollectionView;
NSArray *arrayOfModelsForSecondCollectionView;
}
@end
@implementation YourVC
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Fetch Data For both Segments Using Your Web API Call or Local Database API Call
}
-(IBAction)didChangeSegmentIndex:(id)sender{
    //When segment is changed you need to tell your collectionView to update the data.
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    //When reloadData is call this method will check that which index is selected.
   //And according to selection it will create number of cells.
    if (self.segmentControl.selectedIndex == 0){
        return arrayOfModelsForFirstCollectionView.count;
    }else{
        return arrayOfModelsForSecondCollectionView.count;
    }
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //While creating a cell it will check which segment is selected so it will initialize and create the cell with respect to selection of segments.
    //Hence you have created two different cells in a single collectionView toggling with a segmentControl.
    if (_segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        return [self makeCellForFirstSegmentAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
    else{
        return [self makeCellForSecondSegmentAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
}
-(UITableViewCell *)makeCellForFirstSegmentAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //To show data from array you need to use arrayOfModelsForFirstCollectionView because this array is associated with First Segment Index
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"morningcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.height,cell.frame.size.width)];
    lbl.text = [arrayOfModelsForFirstCollectionView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    return cell;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)makeCellForSecondSegmentAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //To show data from array you need to use arrayOfModelsForSecondCollectionView because this array is associated with Second Segment Index
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"eveningcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,   cell.frame.size.height,cell.frame.size.width)];
    lbl.text = [arrayOfModelsForSecondCollectionView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell addSubview:lbl];
    [lbl setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: It has error @UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"eveningcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];                                                                                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  Error :- No known class method for selector 'dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:'

Comment: use `self.yourCollectionViewOutletName` instead of `collectionView` there.

Comment: it reloads data, but previous values are still there. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SPEeAxMOvmmx8DgINkq_yYuOFssFVNy7)

Comment: Are you using two collectionViews?

Comment: Actually I want to create two collectionviews, On first segment index first collectionview will display and second will be hidden, on second segment index second collectionview will display and first will be hidden. But you say **Do not create two collectionView for the task that you want because you can achieve it using a single collectionView.** so now using only one collectionview.

Comment: [Copy From Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lydDWQBvX-hmSYjPJlIU1rmteGVHcFC3f7xQ0_IjYuc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You have two `IBOutlets` of different `collectionView`. Try to remove one. Because you might be assigning `delegate` & `dataSource` from storyboard which is causing this issue.

Comment: Thanks Bro @SyedQamarAbbas. I solved it. Thanks for your time and effort answering it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165876/discussion-between-syed-qamar-abbas-and-sagar-mahajan).